# Is it safe to proxy a request from https to http?

Tags: ssl, proxy

I have 2 servers, Web and Api.  Web serves up webpages, and Api serves up json.

I want to be able to make ajax calls from Web to Api, but I want to avoid CORS pre-flight requests.  So instead, I thought to proxy all requests for `https://web.com/api/path` to `https://api.com/path`.

The only way I've been able to get this to work is to drop the https when making the request to the api server.  In other words, it goes `https://web.com/some/page` -> `https://web.com/api/path` -> `http://api.com/path`.

Am I leaving myself vulnerable to an attack by dropping the https in my proxy request?

Answer (score 1):

(I would make a comment but I don't have enough rep)

I think this would depend largely on what you mean by proxying.

If you actually use a proxy (that is, your first server relays the request to the second, and it comes back through the first), then you're only as vulnerable as the connection between those two servers.  If they're in physical proximity, over a private network, I wouldn't worry about it too much, as an attacker would have to compromise your physical network.  If they're communicating over open internet, you might have other attacks happen (DNS spoofing comes to mind if you don't supply an actual IP address), and I would not recommend this.

If by 'proxy' you mean the webpage makes an Ajax call to your API server, this would open things up to the same attacks that proxying across the internet could.

Of course, this all depends on what you're serving up in JSON.  If any of it involves authentication or session-related information, I wouldn't leave it unencrypted.  If it's just basic info that's the same for all users, you might not care.  However, a skilled attacker could potentially manipulate the data with a man-in-the-middle attack, so I would still encrypt it.